# rsync how to sync to 192.168... and /sdb

Tags: linux, rsync

I would like to sync a path from `System A` to `System B`. `System B` has only limited free space on `/home`, but enough free space on mounted HDD (`sdb`). When I try to rsync with grsync, I get the following error message:

```
rsync: mkdir "/media/sdb/documents/Letters" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(675) [Receiver=3.1.2]
Exit-Status des rsync-Prozesses:11
```

Source and destination in Grsync are:

- source: `/home/myname/documents/Letters/`
- destination: `192.168.xxx.xxx:/media/sdb/documents/Letters/`

In Grsync, the simulations works well, but execution does not work (see error message above).

Comment: So does `/media/sdb/documents` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo error to me, path in your destination is different from the path shown in error message. 
Guess you need to fix the destination path to lower case 'documents' instead of 'Documents'

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I have corrected it in question. The typo error was unfortunately not the problem.